# Start navigation or maps application on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

Is there a way to start maps or navigation application programmatically on Windows Mobile (6.5)?

I am looking for something similar to Android where you can pass location encoded into uri to view and the system will then automatically start whatever application can handle the uri.

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + mLat + "," + mLon)); 
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);

Is there a way to do something similar in Windows Mobile?

I have a device with both Google Maps and TeleNav GPS installed, but I don't know how to start either of them programmatically or how to pass arguments.

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Google Maps, all you should have to do is start the web browser with the right URL.

The trick is to find an appropriate browser

http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/google-maps-for-mobile/UeOBwm2cNdY

Comment: I've tried that, but the Mobile Explorer browser cannot seem to handle google maps or even m.bing.com/maps (displays black screen in the later case).  May be it is just not going to work.